# ALAsset Photo Library Image Performance Improvements When Its Loading Slow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks

Hi i've got a problem with display an image on my scrollView.

At first i create new UIImageView with asset url:

```
-(void) findLargeImage:(NSNumber*) arrayIndex
{
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep;
    if([myasset defaultRepresentation] == nil) {
        return;
    } else {
        rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    }
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    itemToAdd = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([arrayIndex intValue]*320, 0, 320, 320)];
    itemToAdd.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:itemToAdd];
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.photoPath objectAtIndex:[arrayIndex intValue] ]];
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];
```

}

Where itemToAdd is a UIImageView define in interface:

```
__block UIImageView *itemToAdd;
```

And scrollView define as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __block UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Then in my viewWillAppear i do this:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self findLargeImage:self.actualPhotoIndex];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

But image doesnt appear, should i refresh self.view after add image to scrollView, or should do something else?

Comment: Did you check if it actually goes in the result block?

Comment: Yes, im sure that my method go to success block, and if i send image to another viewController it will be diplayed.

Comment: `__block` is only for local variables. You are trying to put it on a property. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ALAssetsLibrary** block will execute in **separate thread**. So I suggest to do the UI related stuffs in **main thread**.

To do this either use **dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()** or **performSelectorOnMainThread**

**Some Important Notes:**

1. Use AlAsset aspectRatioThumbnail instead of  fullResolutionImage for high performance

   Example:

> ```
>  CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];
>  itemToAdd.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
> ```

**Example:**

```
-(void) findLargeImage:(NSNumber*) arrayIndex
{
 ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
 {

    CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];         

 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    itemToAdd = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([arrayIndex intValue]*320, 0, 320, 320)];
    itemToAdd.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:itemToAdd];

 });//end block


};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.photoPath objectAtIndex:[arrayIndex intValue] ]];
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];

}
```

Also change the order of  viewWillAppear()

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self findLargeImage:self.actualPhotoIndex];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the view from another thread.
You must use the main thread for manipulating the view.

Add image to scrollView using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.scrollView addSubview:itemToAdd];
}
```

or using:

```
[self.scrollView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:itemToAdd waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Please refer:

1. [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I dont know why but when i use first method it blocks my application, and i cant press any button on my view. When i use second method it works fine but it add itemToAdd subView to my self.view When i use this method to add itemToAdd to scrollView and and then add scrollView to self.view it doesnt work.

Comment: replace self.view with self.scrollView

Comment: @edzio27: I think you used dispatch_sync not dispatch_async

Comment: @edzio27: still have issues ?

Comment: Yes, i use [self.scrollView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:itemToAdd waitUntilDone:NO];
 in my block and [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView]; in my viewWillAppear and it still doesnt work.

Comment: check if the scrollView is nil or not

Comment: It is not nil, i declare scrollView with method: - (UIScrollView *) scrollView {
    if(_scrollView == nil) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 320)];
        return _scrollView;
    }
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19930/discussion-between-edzio27-and-midhun-mp)

Comment: @edzio27: please check my chat on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19930/discussion-between-edzio27-and-midhun-mp