# UITableView cell won't select

Tags: uitableview, alassetslibrary

I have a `UITableView` which contains a `UIImage` and a title per cell. I'm getting the image from my db which contains the path of the picture generate via the `ALAssetsLibrary`. Problem is whenever I include the photo in the table, I can't select the cell. Any help would be appreciated

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

}
Person *aPerson = [arrayOfPerson objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.image = background;
cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;

UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:101];
myLabel.text = aPerson.title;

NSString *stPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aPerson.photo];
NSURL *urlNow = [NSURL URLWithString:stPath];

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:urlNow resultBlock:^(ALAsset *imageAsset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *r = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
    UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: r.fullResolutionImage];
    //[cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} failureBlock:nil];
return cell;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't select the cell"? Did you implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1):

New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES` after initializing the object.

```
UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
cellBackgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**Note**:

When you are dealing with Asset Library images, Please look at my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508535/alasset-photo-library-image-performance-improvements-when-its-loading-slow/13508841#13508841) that may help you for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding enabling user interaction both via IB and program but it's still not working